# Why icon is repeating?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use icon as item in menu bar, but when display is bigger than 1366x768 it begins to repeat. Here is the picture what it looks like: 
[image]

Here is the html & css:

```css
.topheader__menu {
  float: right;
  font-size: 5vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 3vmin;
  margin-right: 3vmin;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.topheader__menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.topheader__menu__item {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2ch;
  margin-right: 2ch;
}
.nav_1 {
  background: url(../img/nav-menu/home_bl.png);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.nav_1:hover {
  background: url(../img/nav-menu/home_wh.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="topheader__menu">
  <a class="topheader__menu__item nav_1" href="#">&nbsp</a>
  <a class="topheader__menu__item nav_2" id="current" href="#">About</a>
  <a class="topheader__menu__item nav_3" href="#">Technical</a>
  <a class="topheader__menu__item nav_4" href="#">Products</a>
</div>
```

How should I make it to not repeat if display is bigger than 1366x768?

Comment: put background-repeat:no-repeat to .nav_1

Comment: is image repeating when you are hover the image..?

Comment: Can you give me your site link so i will check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace Your css width this code**

```
.nav_1 {
  background:url(../img/nav-menu/home_bl.png);
  display: block;
  width: 16px;   //image width 
  height: 16px;  //image height
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.nav_1:hover {
  background:url(../img/nav-menu/home_wh.png);
  width: 16px;  //image width 
  height: 16px;  //image height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just using `background`  use `background-image`and add `background-repeat:no-repeat` to the hover state also
like this

```
.nav_1 {
background-image: url(../img/nav-menu/home_bl.png);
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.nav_1:hover {
background-image: url(../img/nav-menu/home_wh.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put below code

```
.nav_1 {
background: url(../img/nav-menu/home_bl.png) no-repeat;
display: block;
width: 100%;}

.nav_1:hover {
background: url(../img/nav-menu/home_wh.png) no-repeat;
}
```

or

```
.nav_1 {
background: url(../img/nav-menu/home_bl.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
display: block;
width: 100%;}

   .nav_1:hover {
background: url(../img/nav-menu/home_wh.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: it still being repeating